# Find indices where df is null

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas (master branch or upcoming 0.14) how can I find the indices where my dataframe is null?

When I do:

```
df.isnull()
```

I get a boolean dataframe of the same size as `df`

If I do:

```
df.isnull().index
```

I get the index of the original `df`.

What I want is are the indices of those rows with NaN entries (either on some column, or on all columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would drop to numpy to do this a little faster:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 1], [0, np.nan], [1, 2]])

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
    0   1
0 NaN   1
1   0 NaN
2   1   2

In [13]: pd.isnull(df.values)
Out[13]:
array([[ True, False],
       [False,  True],
       [False, False]], dtype=bool)

In [14]: pd.isnull(df.values).any(1)
Out[14]: array([ True,  True, False], dtype=bool)

In [15]: np.nonzero(pd.isnull(df.values).any(1))
Out[15]: (array([0, 1]),)

In [16]: df.index[np.nonzero(pd.isnull(df.values).any(1))]
Out[16]: Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64')
```

To see some timings, with a slightly larger df:

```
In [21]: df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 1], [0, np.nan], [1, 2]] * 1000)

In [22]: %timeit np.nonzero(pd.isnull(df.values).any(1))
10000 loops, best of 3: 85.8 µs per loop

In [23]: %timeit df.index[df.isnull().any(1)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 629 µs per loop
```

and if you cared about the index (rather than the position):

```
In [24]: %timeit df.index[np.nonzero(pd.isnull(df.values).any(1))]
10000 loops, best of 3: 172 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 9):

```
df.index[df.isnull().any(axis=1)]
```

The `.any(axis=1)` will give you True/False for each row whether there is at least one NaN value. With this you can do a boolean indexing of the index to find the indexes where df is null.